# VBA - Loading Arrays, Skipping Blanks

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, office365

Sorry I don't show my variables or anything, tried to give information only pertaining to the questions.  This 1 Sub is huge.

Currently my code allows a user to select multiple files, the files selected will be sorted in a specific format, then loaded into 2 different arrays.  Currently loads Columns D:E into 1 array and Columns I:K into another array (from selected files `QSResultFileWS`, and returns those arrays to my destination `FormattingWS`.  I'm still trying to learn arrays so if the methodology I used to do this isn't proper, be gentle.

```
FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.XLSX), *.XLSX", Title:="Select all files needing analyzed", MultiSelect:=True)       'if file types change to csv or something else, this needs changed
        
       If Not IsArray(FileToOpen) Then Exit Sub
  
        With FormattingWS
            .Range("D10").Value = "Sample Name"
            .Range("E10").Value = "Target Name"
            .Range("F10").Value = "Crt"
            .Range("H10").Value = "Crt SD"
            .Range("G10").Value = "Crt Average"
            .Range("M10").Value = "Final Result"
            .Range("N10").Value = "Final Crt"
        End With                
'select all result files at once
        For Each ResultFile In FileToOpen   '---------------------------------Import Result Files (Start)----------------------------
            Set QSResultFileWB = Workbooks.Open(ResultFile)
            Set QSResultFileWS = QSResultFileWB.Sheets("Results")
                TotalRows = 0
                Counter = 0
            With QSResultFileWS
                Set SampleName = .Range("A1:Q50").Find("Sample Name")       'find column that I want to count all the rows - This column will always have data regardless of any blanks in other columns
                SampleNameLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, SampleName.Column).End(xlUp).Row
                Set SampleNameStart = .Range("D" & SampleName.Row).Offset(1, 0) 'offset 1 row to avoid grabbing the headers
                QSResultFileWSLastUsedColumn = .Cells(20, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column   'row 20 is where headers start               '------------------------------Sort Data to get Targets Grouped Together(Start)-----------------------------
                
                .Sort.SortFields.Clear
                .Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("D21:D" & SampleNameLastRow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
                .Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("E21:E" & SampleNameLastRow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortTextAsNumbers  'blanks will be present in this column
                With QSResultFileWS.Sort
                    .SetRange Range(Cells(20, 1), Cells(SampleNameLastRow, QSResultFileWSLastUsedColumn))
                    .Header = xlYes
                    .MatchCase = False
                    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
                    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
                    .Apply
                End With                                                                                '------------------------------Sort Data to get Targets Grouped Together(End)-----------------------------
                
                With QSResultFileWS.Range("D" & SampleNameStart.Row, "D" & SampleNameLastRow)
                    For Each r In .Rows
                        If Application.CountA(r) <> 0 Then
                            Counter = Counter + 1
                        End If
                    Next r
                    TotalRows = Counter
                End With
                sampleArrayDE = .Range("D21:E" & SampleNameLastRow).Value   'Load Columns D:E into Array from Source WB - if row has blanks, Column E will also have blanks, Column D will not have blanks
                sampleArrayIK = .Range("I21:K" & SampleNameLastRow).Value   'Load Columns I:K into Array from Source WB - if row has blanks, Columns I:K will all contain blanks
            End With
            
            With FormattingWS
                DlastRow = FormattingWS.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
                Set DEColumnRng = FormattingWS.Range("D" & DlastRow).Offset(1, 0)
                Set IKColumnRng = FormattingWS.Range("F" & DlastRow).Offset(1, 0)
                FormattingWS.Range(DEColumnRng, "E" & (DEColumnRng.Row + TotalRows) - 1).Value = sampleArrayDE 'Return D:E Array to Destination WB - DEColumnRng gives where the next data set should start populating - if File 1 then data starts populating in 11, then ((add TotalRows) - 1) to return everything initially loaded to array
                FormattingWS.Range(IKColumnRng, "H" & (DEColumnRng.Row + TotalRows) - 1).Value = sampleArrayIK 'Return I:K Array to Destination WB
            End With
                Erase sampleArrayDE
                Erase sampleArrayIK
            QSResultFileWS.Parent.Close False
        Next ResultFile                     '---------------------------------Import Result Files (End)-------------------------------
```

Code works fine as is, however there are blanks rows in certain columns that I don't care about returning.

For example:
Column D - will always have a string value - but the entire row will not always have string values for columns E, I, J, K (from `QSResultFileWS` - E I J K translate to E F G H on `FormattingWS`)

1 "data set" in the selected files will have 112 rows, I only need 90, the other 22 rows in the data set will be blank with the exception of Column D.  Once I apply my sorting, those 22 blanks are always at the top (see picture)

[image: Blanks at top]

For another visual, here is where 1 data set stops (row 122) and another begins.

[image: End of Data Set 1]

This is how it looks on my Destination WB (Columns I'm importing data to on this WB are Columns D,E,F,G,H.  Columns M and N are filled in with the rest of my code I did not provide).

Finally my question, is there a way I can tell the arrays to not return Column D information if the row is blank for Columns E I J K?  Or if it makes it any easier, only if Column E is blank.  If E is blank the rest of the columns should also be blank.

I figure before all of this code happens, I could add in a reverse loop and delete all those rows and if that's less of a hassle I can do that, but in my never-ending attempt to learn arrays I thought I would ask.  Any feedback/explanations on my current method is welcomed!

Thanks!

EDIT W/ Solution from Chris

```
 FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.XLSX), *.XLSX", Title:="Select all files needing analyzed", MultiSelect:=True)       'if file types change to csv or something else, this needs changed
        
        If Not IsArray(FileToOpen) Then Exit Sub

        With FormattingWS
            .Range("D10").Value = "Sample Name"
            .Range("E10").Value = "Target Name"
            .Range("F10").Value = "Crt"
            .Range("H10").Value = "Crt SD"
            .Range("G10").Value = "Crt Average"
            .Range("M10").Value = "Final Result"
            .Range("N10").Value = "Final Crt"
        End With
                
                'select all result files at once
        For Each ResultFile In FileToOpen   '---------------------------------Import Result Files (Start)----------------------------
            Set QSResultFileWB = Workbooks.Open(ResultFile)
            Set QSResultFileWS = QSResultFileWB.Sheets("Results")
                TotalRows = 0
                Counter = 0
            With QSResultFileWS
                Set SampleName = .Range("A1:Q50").Find("Sample Name")
                SampleNameLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, SampleName.Column).End(xlUp).Row
                Set SampleNameStart = .Range("D" & SampleName.Row).Offset(1, 0)
                QSResultFileWSLastUsedColumn = .Cells(20, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column               '------------------------------Sort Data to get Targets Grouped Together(Start)-----------------------------
                
                .Sort.SortFields.Clear
                .Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("D21:D" & SampleNameLastRow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
                .Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("E21:E" & SampleNameLastRow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlsortextasnumbers
                With QSResultFileWS.Sort
                    .SetRange Range(Cells(20, 1), Cells(SampleNameLastRow, QSResultFileWSLastUsedColumn))
                    .Header = xlYes
                    .MatchCase = False
                    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
                    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
                    .Apply
                End With                                                                                    '------------------------------Sort Data to get Targets Grouped Together(End)-----------------------------
                
                With QSResultFileWS.Range("D" & SampleNameStart.Row, "D" & SampleNameLastRow)
                    Dim r As Range
                    For Each r In .Rows
                        If r.Offset(0, 1).Value = vbNullString Then
                            r.Value = vbNullString
                        End If
                        If Application.CountA(r) <> 0 Then
                            Counter = Counter + 1
                        End If
                    Next r
                    TotalRows = Counter
                End With
                Set rng = .Range("D21:E" & SampleNameLastRow)
                Set rng2 = .Range("I21:K" & SampleNameLastRow)
                sampleArrayDE = rng.Worksheet.Evaluate("FILTER(" & rng.Address & "," & rng.Columns(2).Address & "<>"""")")
                sampleArrayIK = rng2.Worksheet.Evaluate("FILTER(" & rng2.Address & "," & rng2.Columns(1).Address & "<>"""")")
            End With
            
            With FormattingWS
                DlastRow = FormattingWS.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
                Set DEColumnRng = FormattingWS.Range("D" & DlastRow).Offset(1, 0)
                Set IKColumnRng = FormattingWS.Range("F" & DlastRow).Offset(1, 0)
                FormattingWS.Range(DEColumnRng, "E" & (DEColumnRng.Row + TotalRows) - 1).Value = sampleArrayDE
                FormattingWS.Range(IKColumnRng, "H" & (DEColumnRng.Row + TotalRows) - 1).Value = sampleArrayIK
            End With
                Erase sampleArrayDE
                Erase sampleArrayIK
            QSResultFileWS.Parent.Close False
        Next ResultFile                     '---------------------------------Import Result Files (End)-------------------------------
```

With my brief understanding of Chris's suggestion, this is what I came up with and it seems to be working!

Since I added

```
                       If r.Offset(0, 1).Value = vbNullString Then
                            r.Value = vbNullString
                        End If
```

I think I can change the filtering code back to what Chris originally suggested and it should work the same, but I really don't want to touch anything lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `FILTER` function to remove the blanks.

Replace you lines load the arrays

```
sampleArrayDE = .Range("D21:E" & SampleNameLastRow).Value
```

with this

```
Set rng = .Range("D21:E" & SampleNameLastRow)
sampleArrayDE = rng.Worksheet.Evaluate("FILTER(" & rng.Address & "," & rng.Columns(1).Address & "<>"""")")
```

Notes:

1. Requires a version of Excel that supports Dynamic Arrays
2. Add `Dim rng As range` with your other Variables
3. You might want to account for the case where `Find` returns `Nothing`
4. There are a couple of other issues

- [`range.Find`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) needs some parameters specified.  See in the link the note starting *The settings for LookIn, LookAt, SearchOrder, and MatchByte are saved each time you use this method.*
- You have some unqualified range references.  Add a worksheet reference to these

```vb
            .Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("D21:D" & SampleNameLastRow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
                                       ^^^
            .Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("E21:E" & SampleNameLastRow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
                                       ^^^

            With QSResultFileWS.Sort
                .SetRange Range(Cells(20, 1), Cells(SampleNameLastRow, QSResultFileWSLastUsedColumn))
                          ^^^   ^^^           ^^^
```

Comment: I got your code to work, instead changed the 2nd argument from Columns(1) to Columns(2) - the string to be searched.  Because I'm counting the used rows (SampleNameLastRow) pre-filter and then returning the array on next available line + total rows, it's returning more rows than needed, but I think I can mess with it.  

As for the missing worksheet references, is the object not assumed if it lies within a 'With End With' block?  At the time, putting the object reference seemed redundant to me?

I shouldn't have left the '.Find' code in there, that's all coming out, so that's my bad.

Comment: Re _is the object not assumed if it lies within a 'With End With' block?_ No, the With object is referenced by a leading `.` Change `Cells` to `.Cells`